# How is the Möbius function in boolean sets?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, functions, mobius-function

Although the text is a little long, the text is very simple so that're familiar with the matter.

I did not understand two passages in the text. Could you help me show that:

- $I'= I \cup M$ and only if $Q$ is an antichain; and
- $Q$ appeared that in fact is an antichain.

---

[image]